# What is the meaing of "for (Person obj: persons)" in the following java code? Also kindly let me know the use of : in java

Tags: java

```
System.out.println ("\nPolymorphism:");
Person[] persons = { new Person("Abu"), 
                     new Student ("Ben", 222), 
                     new Staff ("Carlo", 3000),
                     new Lecturer ("Donna", 5000, "TCP1101")
                    };
for (Person obj: persons)
   System.out.println (obj.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [*`enhanced for` statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

```
for (SomeType foo : iterableElement){
    doSomeStuff(foo);
}
```

- it will iterate over `iterableElement` which is an iterable/array of object of type `SomeType`/subtype of `SomeType`
- inside the loop, the current instance will be called `foo`, and we will call `doSomeStuff(foo);` on each object

---

Also `toString();` into a print is useless, the code will go find it itself

```
System.out.println (obj); // is good
```

Use `toString();` when you want to get it back bu not in a print, like :

```
String foo = myPerson.toString();
char firstChar = foo.getCharAt(0);
```

Comment: The correct name is an *enhanced for statement*. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: "or object of type SomeType," an *array* with elements of type `SomeType` (or a subtype thereof).

Answer (score 0):

`for (Person obj: persons)` mean that for every element of `persons` execute {....} taking that object in obj.

syntax:

```
for (datatype name : array) {...}
```